# How to do a simple form-urlencoded POST request in AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking-2

How do I replicate this NSURLConnection code in AFNetworking 2.0?

```
NSString *post = @"key=xxx";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is given in the AFNetworking page [github link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

The code for sending post request is below, just import the AFNeworking folder in your project in xocde and add necessary frameworks [getting started with afnetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"key": @"xxx"};
[manager POST:@"http://test.com" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: use the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` provided by AFNetworking.

According to the [document](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#url-form-parameter-encoding):

```
[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters];
```

sends:

```
POST http://example.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar&baz[]=1&baz[]=2&baz[]=3
```

If you are using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

// you can use different serializer for response.
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to **POST form-data with AFNetworking** you must create this format out of your NSDictionary:

say you have to send these params :

```
{
  key1 = val1;
  key2 = val2;
  key3 = val3;
}
```

create this format and encode data using UTF8Encoding :

```
key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3
```

You can use this formatting :

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSArray *allKeys = [dict allKeys];
for (NSString *key in allKeys) {
    [str appendString:key];
    [str appendString:@"="];
    [str appendString:[dict valueForKey:key]];
    [str appendString:@"&"];
}
[str deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([str length]-1, 1)];
NSData *requestBodyData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

AFNetworking creates `NSMutableRequest`. In the `HTTPBody` of NSMutableRequest instance pass this `requestBodyData`.

Done.